# CORS Error Rails 6 api backend + Angular Frontend

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, nginx, ruby-on-rails-6, puma

I am getting following error even when I have rack-cors gem installed and utilised in my Rails 6 api only application.
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'api.backend.com' from origin 'frontend.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I have tried adding Angular domains as origins but no luck. I also tried to add it to application.rb and config.ru. Noting has worked, and I am confused.